Why are Noto Serif Tibetan font glyphs stretching outside the bounding box of their containing div?


.pb-64 {
    padding-bottom: 64px;
}

.p-16 {
    padding: 16px;
}
.gap-16 {
    gap: 16px;
}
.flex-col {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.w-full {
    width: 100%;
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
* {
    border: none;
}
.flex-col {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-shrink {
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.mb-64 {
    margin-bottom: 64px;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.items-stretch {
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.block {
    display: block;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.transition-colors {
    transition-property: color, background-color, border-color, text-decoration-color, fill, stroke;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition-duration: 150ms;
}

.gap-8 {
    gap: 8px;
}
.flex-col {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
.items-center {
    align-items: center;
}

.flex-col {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.leading-\[1\.4\] {
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.font-normal {
    font-weight: 400;
}
.text-6xl {
    font-size: 3.75rem;
    line-height: 1;
}
.block {
    display: block;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.font-NotoSerifTibetan {
  font-family: "Noto Serif Tibetan", serif;
  font-optical-sizing: auto;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}
.text-gray-500 {
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgb(107 114 128 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
.transition-opacity {
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    transition-duration: 150ms;
}
.opacity-0 {
    opacity: 0;
}
.p-8 {
    padding: 8px;
}
.w-32 {
    width: 32px;
}
.h-32 {
    height: 32px;
}
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Serif+Tibetan:wght@100..900&display=swap');
</style><div class="relative w-full pb-64 p-16 flex flex-col gap-16"><div class="relative flex flex-shrink flex-col mb-64" style="justify-content: center; row-gap: 0px; z-index: 2;"><div class="relative flex items-stretch" style="justify-content: center; row-gap: 8px; z-index: 2;"><div class="relative block" style="width: 132px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="relative [&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 itemss-center" href="" rowinddex="0" columninddex="0"><div class="relative flex flex-col items-center"><span class="relative block font-normal text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཀ</span><div class="relative text-gray-500">ka</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="0" columnindex="1" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཁ</span><div class="text-gray-500">kɦa</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="0" columnindex="2" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ག</span><div class="text-gray-500">ga</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="0" columnindex="3" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ང</span><div class="text-gray-500">ṅa</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="0" columnindex="4" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཅ</span><div class="text-gray-500">txa</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="0" columnindex="5" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཆ</span><div class="text-gray-500">txɦa</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div></div><div class="relative flex items-stretch" style="justify-content: center; row-gap: 8px; z-index: 2;"><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="1" columnindex="0" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཇ</span><div class="text-gray-500">dja</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="1" columnindex="1" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཉ</span><div class="text-gray-500">nẏa</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="1" columnindex="2" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཏ</span><div class="text-gray-500">ta</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="1" columnindex="3" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཐ</span><div class="text-gray-500">tɦa</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="1" columnindex="4" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ད</span><div class="text-gray-500">da</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="1" columnindex="5" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ན</span><div class="text-gray-500">na</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div></div><div class="relative flex items-stretch" style="justify-content: center; row-gap: 8px; z-index: 2;"><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="2" columnindex="0" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">པ</span><div class="text-gray-500">pa</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="2" columnindex="1" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཕ</span><div class="text-gray-500">pɦa</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="2" columnindex="2" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">བ</span><div class="text-gray-500">ba</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="2" columnindex="3" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">མ</span><div class="text-gray-500">ma</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="2" columnindex="4" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཙ</span><div class="text-gray-500">tsa</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="2" columnindex="5" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཚ</span><div class="text-gray-500">tsɦa</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div></div><div class="relative flex items-stretch" style="justify-content: center; row-gap: 8px; z-index: 2;"><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="3" columnindex="0" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཛ</span><div class="text-gray-500">dza</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="3" columnindex="1" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཝ</span><div class="text-gray-500">wa</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="3" columnindex="2" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཞ</span><div class="text-gray-500">ja</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="3" columnindex="3" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཟ</span><div class="text-gray-500">za</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; margin-right: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="3" columnindex="4" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">འ</span><div class="text-gray-500">hɦ</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div><div class="block" style="width: 132px; margin-left: 4px; z-index: 2;"><a class="[&amp;_i]:hover:opacity-100 hover:text-violet-600 transition-colors flex flex-col gap-8 items-center" rowindex="3" columnindex="5" href=""><div class="flex flex-col items-center"><span class="block font-semibold text-6xl leading-[1.4] font-NotoSerifTibetan">ཡ</span><div class="text-gray-500">ya</div></div><i class="opacity-0 transition-opacity hover:text-violet-600 inline-block w-32 h-32 p-8"><svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M15.54,16.54a1,1,0,0,1-.71-.3,1,1,0,0,1,0-1.41,4,4,0,0,0,0-5.66,1,1,0,0,1,1.41-1.41,6,6,0,0,1,0,8.48A1,1,0,0,1,15.54,16.54Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path><path d="M11.38,4.08a1,1,0,0,0-1.09.21L6.59,8H4a2,2,0,0,0-2,2v4a2,2,0,0,0,2,2H6.59l3.7,3.71A1,1,0,0,0,11,20a.84.84,0,0,0,.38-.08A1,1,0,0,0,12,19V5A1,1,0,0,0,11.38,4.08Z" class="fill-gray-800 dark:fill-gray-400"></path></svg></i></a></div></div></div></div>




Right click on the HTML to inspect after running the above example to see.
Why is the gray area (behind the blue square), stretching outside of the blue square? The gray area is the hoverable area of the .block area, which is the same as the ::selection area of the E-shaped glyph. But the blue square is the bounding box of the div. Why isn't it covering the entire glyph?
I played with line-height a lot, but shouldn't it work fine without touching line height? And I still couldn't get it to work with changing line-height on every element in the DOM tree. I tried to narrow it down to a deliverable isolated example, but every time I started from scratch to reproduce, I couldn't reproduce, so something funky is occurring with my configuration of CSS classes.

You are mentioning that issue is due to noto serif font but it's not but more of language or symbols you are using. If you remove the font style then also issue persists. You can also try to inspect English words as they are not overflowing.

What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

I'm afraid there is not much you can do but to tweak heights and offsets manually. The tibetan Noto has quite large descender values. If you need more predictable bounding boxes you may render the glyphs on a canvas or as SVG with a library like opentype.js

@BrettDonald I basically want to have a bounding box around the glyph (tight), so I know what to expect when I add surrounding elements and padding, etc.. I would also like this to work for any font (not just Tibetan).
